# component in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I used from vue-router

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: login
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: Register
    }
]})
```

router read all style in components and apply style from other component in active component

Example :

Register Component :

```
<template>
<div class="test">

</div>
</template>
<style  scoped>
    .test {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Login Component :

```
<template>
<div class="test">

</div>
</template>
<style  scoped>
    .test { 
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
</style>
```

Result:

> after get login or register route, test tag is red background and
>   black border

thanks for help me :)

Comment: Can you provide your webpack config ? I think the problem can be here.

Comment: use your browsers developer tools to find out where the styles come from

Comment: tanks my friends!

I added lang="scss" in style tag and style worked only this component :)